# Как записать длинный bash-овский конвеер в python переменную?

Tags: python, bash

Есть удобный bash-конвеер, который выдаёт в stdout нужную информацию. Как записать результат команды не на экран, а в переменную python?
Пробовал:

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output(['smartctl', '-a', '/dev/sda', '|', 'grep', 'Device Model', '|', 'tr', '-s', '" "', '|', 'cut', '-f3,4', '-d" "'])
```

В результате исключение:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HDD.py", line 3, in <module>
    output = subprocess.check_output(['smartctl', '-a', '/dev/sda', '|', 'grep', 'Device Model', '|', 'tr', '-s', '" "', '|', 'cut', '-f3,4', '-d" "'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 223, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['smartctl', '-a', '/dev/sda', '|', 'grep', 'Device Model', '|', 'tr', '-s', '" "', '|', 'cut', '-f3,4', '-d" "']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Также пробовал для упрощения:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen("smartctl -a /dev/sda | grep Model".split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = process.communicate()
print(output)
```

Тут уже проблема в другом: думает, что это всё аргументы для команды smartctl...:

```
ERROR: smartctl takes ONE device name as the final command-line argument.
You have provided 4 device names:
/dev/sda
|
grep
Model

Use smartctl -h to get a usage summary
```

Подскажите, как это правильно сделать?

Сам скрипт bash, как вы могли догадаться:

```
smartctl -a /dev/sda | grep Device\ Model | tr -s " " | cut -f3,4 -d' '
```

Comment: Вам с большей вероятностью помогут, если вы напишите, какое именно исключение вылетает. А ещё лучше - приведите полный трэйсбек.

Comment: Всё, кроме первой команды, реализуется средствами самого языка Python, не надо над ним издеваться.

Comment: Добавил исключение в первом + ошибку в bash.

Comment: Кстати, по техническим причинам проект разрабатывается на версии python 2.7.15. Это может как то влиять на эти команды?

Comment: *думает, что это всё аргументы для команды smartctl* — ну так и запускайте команду как скрипт для оболочки: отдельно "sh" (или "bash", если надо), отдельно первый аргумент: "-c", отдельно второй аргумент: "smartctl -a /dev/sda | grep Device\ Model | tr -s ' ' | cut -f3,4 -d' '"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Если нужно вызывать баш-портянку с пайпами и без `shell=True`, разбей команду на отдельные `Popen`ы с редиректом вывода в `subprocess.PIPE`. Пример:

   ```
   smartctl = subprocess.Popen(['smartctl', '-a', '/dev/sda'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   grep = subprocess.Popen(['grep', 'Device Model'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=smartctl.stdout)
   tr = subprocess.Popen(['tr', '-s', ' '], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=grep.stdout)
   cut = subprocess.check_output(['cut', '-f3,4', '-d', ' '], stdin=tr.stdout)
   ```
2. `'-d" "'` - это два отдельных аргумента и их необходимо разбить на `'-d', ' '`
3. Не особо страшно, но эскейпить пробел как в командной строке необязательно:

   ```
   ['tr', '-s', ' ']
   ```

   справится не хуже, чем

   ```
   ['tr', '-s', '" "']
   ```

   а читается легче.
4. Для полноты картины - можно, конечно, использовать `shell=True` (команда спавнится в отдельной оболочке, а-ля `sh -c 'ls -l'`, тогда можно передать команду прямым текстом:

   ```
   process = subprocess.Popen("smartctl -a /dev/sda | grep Model", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
   ```

   Но! **`shell=True` может быть капитальной дыркой в безопасности**. Подробнее и пример [в документации](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).

Answer (score 2):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# Исходная команда:
# smartctl -a /dev/sda | grep Device\ Model | tr -s " " | cut -f3,4 -d' '

# Разбиваем на части, подавая stdout одной программы на выход stdin другой:
process_1 = Popen(['smartctl', '-a', '/dev/sda'], stdout=PIPE)
process_2 = Popen(['grep', 'Device Model'], stdin=process_1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
process_3 = Popen(['tr', '-s', ' '], stdin=process_2.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
process_4 = Popen(['cut', '-f3,4', '-d', ' '], stdin=process_3.stdout, stdout=PIPE)

# Получаем данные из stdout
(output, err) = process_4.communicate()

# Код завершения
exit_code = process_4.wait()

print output
```

`smartctl` запускается из-под `root`, поэтому скрипт нужно запустить так: `sudo python smartctl.py`

Вывод:

```
Samsung SSD
```

Подсмотрел решение [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17129244/9435985).

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что могло пойти не так...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NelLc.png

Comment: @Chudvan выглядит так, будто `|`, `grep` и `foo` передались `ls` как аргументы. Попробуйте занести их в одну строку.

Comment: @Chudvan, обновил ответ

Answer (score 1):

Я в своем коде использовал такую конструкцию:

```
proc = subprocess.run(*ваша команда*,
                      timeout = *ваш таймаут, если есть*,
                      input = *инпут для команды*,
                      stdout = subprocess.PIPE, 
                      stderr = subprocess.PIPE, 
                      encoding='utf-8', 
                      shell = True)
```

После чего можно использовать `proc.stdout` и `proc.stderr` для чтения вывода команды.

`check_output()` является несколько ограниченной функцией, например, она не может задать таймаут на выполнение подпроцесса.

Поэтому лично я предпочитаю `run()` как более гибкую. Так же `check_output()`, как и `run()` кидает исключение, если процесс вернул ненулевой код

Comment: К сожалению, по техническим причинам проект до сих пор на версии python 2.7.15, там ещё нет атрибута run в модуле subprocess. Но спасибо за ответ!